# Не проходит сигнал или не происходит соединения в Qt когда оба объекта соединения находятся в другом потоке

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Пишу небольшой сервер, где при нажатии кнопки создаётся новый поток (th) и там запускается TCP слушатель определённого порта. При каждом новом TCP подключении необходимо делать два новых коннекта объектов, оба которых созданы и работают в потоке (th).

```
std::thread th([this]() -> void {
    while (true) {
        std::unique_ptr<Bs> bs = std::make_unique<Bs>();
        bs->GetTcpServer()->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9005);
        connect(bs->GetTcpServer(), SIGNAL(newConnection()), bs.get(), SLOT(ConnectionWasEstablished()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
        connect(bs.get(), SIGNAL(update_server_logs(QString)), this, SLOT(UpdateServerLog(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
        while (!bs->IsConnected()) {  // Ждём следующего подключения.
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        }
        bs_list_.push_back(std::move(bs));
    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что при подключении TCP клиента до соответствующих слотов сигнал не доходит. Всё что я смог нагуглить - это то что скорее всего в новом потоке требуется свой «Event loop», чтобы мочь обрабатывать сигналы, но как его создать в новом потоке не понял.

#### Проблема решена:

Всё заработало когда я создал поток по [статье](http://vasinnet.blogspot.com/2012/08/recommended-way-to-using-qthread.html) которую нашёл Bearded Beaver. Добиться работоспособности с std::thread я так и не смог(. Большое спасибо всем кто помог, особенно Bearded Beaver и ixSci.

Comment: Интересно, а если убрать `Qt::QueuedConnection`?

Comment: Вам нужен `QThread` и запуск задания в потоке через `QObject::moveToThread`

Comment: @ixSci он появился там при попытке решить проблемы. А так все три варианта не к чему не приводят.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver спасибо, сейчас попробую порыть.

Comment: наконец нашел статью с нормально (ну как нормально - в том же виде, как в таких ситуациях я пишу у себя) написанным кодом - http://vasinnet.blogspot.com/2012/08/recommended-way-to-using-qthread.html

Comment: @BeardedBeaver спасибо, я пока пытаюсь вникнуть в вашу предыдущую статью.

Comment: вторая статья по сути является написанным кодом к теории, описанной в первой

Comment: @BeardedBeaver а как в такой поток передать объекты или запустить в качестве главной функции внешнее замыкание?

Comment: Поток вы создаете обычный `QThread`, а в него через `moveToThread` передаете объект-наследник от QObject, к слотам которого вы хотите присоединять сигналы. Далее через `start()` запускаете цикл обработки событий потока, и объект, который вы передали в поток становится способен принимать сигналы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в цикл `QCoreApplication::processEvents();`, должно помочь.

---

Вообще говоря, Ваш код ужасен. Используете Qt? Используйте его возможности, его потоки и всё, что с ними связано. Вот статья про то, как правильно работать с QThread: [Threads Events QObjects](http://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects), там же есть русский перевод.

Comment: Реализация Qt потоков через наследование мне показалась ужасной.

Comment: @mrFieldy, этого делать и не нужно. Сейчас попробую найти статью по теме.

Comment: Добавил QCoreApplication::processEvents(); в оба while`а. Это не помогло.

Comment: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/ статья, на которую я ссылался в комментарии к вопросу, про нее же говорит и ixSci. Видимо :)

Comment: @mrFieldy, обновил ответ, добавив ссылку. Beaver, я имел в виду другую статью.

Answer (score 1):

На случай если статья-источник потеряется, продублирую сюда решение из нее с некоторыми своими ремарками:

> Не создавайте подклассов QThread!
>
> Используйте `moveToThread()` и "рабочий" класс-наследник от `QObject`.
>
> Далее описано, как Вы должны реализовать многопоточную операцию, используя класс `QThread`.
>
> Создайте класс-работник, который унаследован от класса `QObject`.
>   Этот класс должен определять следующие сигналы и слоты:
>
> - Слот (слоты), в котором происходит работа.
> - Сигнал, который информирует вызывающий код о завершении работы.
> - Опционально, сигнал, который информирует вызывающий код в случае возникновения ошибок.

Класс-работник:

```
 class Worker : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
     explicit Worker(QObject * parent  = nullptr);
 public slots:
     void process();

 signals:
     void finished();
     void error(QString err);
};
```

Использование в отдельном потоке:

```
// Создание потока
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Worker* worker = new Worker();

// Перемещаем класс-работник в отдельный поток
worker->moveToThread(thread);

// Связываем сигнал об ошибки со слотом обработки ошибок
connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorHandler(QString)));

// Соединяем сигнал started потока, со слотом process класса-работника, чтобы выполнение началось сразу после запуска потока
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));

// Обеспечиваем завершение работы потока и автоматическое очищение памяти объектов потока и работника при завершении работы
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

// Запускаем цикл обработки событий для потока, теперь объект готов реагировать на сигналы
thread->start();
```

От себя добавлю, что такие воркеры отлично справляются с ролью потоков-демонов типа "висеть в памяти и при поступлении сигнала как-то на него реагировать", для этого запуск задачи цепляем не к сигналу `started` потока, а к тому сигналу, на который надо реагировать и не испускаем сигнал `finished` при завершении слота с задачей, тогда объект продолжит ждать поступления новых сигналов.

З.Ы. Пример кода старый, коннекты написаны в Qt4-style, лучше переделать на "новый" синтаксис.